# Returning the TABLE_NAME from GET DIAGNOSTICS MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to return the `TABLE_NAME` or query when an error occurs within a stored procedure in MySQL 5.7. I currently use this exception handler:

```
GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1
@sql_state = RETURNED_SQLSTATE, 
@errno = MYSQL_ERRNO,
@errtxt = MESSAGE_TEXT
@tbl_nm = TABLE_NAME;
```

Doing `SELECT @tbl_nm` returns a blank value. Ideally I would like to return the table of where the error occurred or better still the whole query where the error occurred?

Comment: You are out of luck as TABLE_NAME is always empty, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/diagnostics-area.html

Comment: That is frustrating, do you know if there's a way to get the query that caused the error?

Comment: I'm not aware any solutions that would allow you to get the query that caused the error. Not even the sql standard includes this feature.